# Need help in the query (oracle 11 g)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

First of all, these are my create_table statements.

```
/*---  Base tables ---*/

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUST_ID     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CUST_FNAME  VARCHAR(15),    
CUST_LNAME  VARCHAR(15),
CUST_HP     NUMBER(10),
CUST_EMAIL  VARCHAR(40),
primary key (CUST_ID)   
);

CREATE TABLE STAFF(
STAFF_ID        NUMBER(12) NOT NULL,
STAFF_FNAME     VARCHAR(15),
STAFF_LNAME     VARCHAR(15),
STAFF_DOB       Date,
STAFF_AGE       NUMBER(2),
STAFF_ADDRESS   VARCHAR(70),
STAFF_HP        NUMBER(10),
STAFF_SALARY    NUMBER(6,2),
primary key (STAFF_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER(
SUPP_ID         VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
SUPP_NAME       VARCHAR(30),
SUPP_TEL        NUMBER(10),
SUPP_EMAIL      VARCHAR(25),
SUPP_ADDRESS    VARCHAR(80),
SUPP_CITY       VARCHAR(20),
SUPP_STATE      VARCHAR(10),
SUPP_ZIP        NUMBER(5),
primary key (SUPP_ID) 
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT(
PROD_ID         VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PROD_NAME       VARCHAR(30),
PROD_DESC       VARCHAR(70),
R_UNIT_PRICE    NUMBER(3,2) DEFAULT 4.50,
L_UNIT_PRICE    NUMBER(3,2) DEFAULT 5.00,
primary key (PROD_ID)
);     

CREATE TABLE INGREDIENT(
ING_ID          VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ING_NAME        VARCHAR(20),
ING_DESC        VARCHAR(60),
primary key (ING_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE TOPPING(
TOP_ID          VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
TOP_NAME        VARCHAR(20),
TOP_DESC        VARCHAR(40),
TOP_PRICE       NUMBER(2,2),
primary key (TOP_ID)
);

/*---  Child tables  ---*/

CREATE TABLE ORDERS(
ORDERS_ID       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CUST_ID         VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
STAFF_ID        NUMBER(12) NOT NULL,
TOTAL_PRICE     NUMBER(5,2),
ORDERS_DATE     DATE,
primary key (ORDERS_ID),
foreign key (CUST_ID) references CUSTOMER(CUST_ID),
foreign key (STAFF_ID) references STAFF(STAFF_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ORD_DETAIL(
SK1_ID          NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
ORDERS_ID       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PROD_ID         VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
TOP_ID          VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
TEATYPE         VARCHAR(8),
CUPSIZE         CHAR(1),
QTY             NUMBER(2),
CONSTRAINT CHK_CUPSIZE CHECK (CUPSIZE = 'R' OR CUPSIZE = 'L'),
CONSTRAINT CHK_TEATYPE CHECK (TEATYPE = 'Oolong' OR TEATYPE = 'Jasmine'),
primary key (SK1_ID),
foreign key (ORDERS_ID) references ORDERS(ORDERS_ID),
foreign key (PROD_ID) references PRODUCT(PROD_ID)，
foreign key (TOP_ID) references TOPPING(TOP_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PROD_ING(
PROD_ID     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ING_ID      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,   
primary key (PROD_ID , ING_ID),
foreign key (PROD_ID) references PRODUCT(PROD_ID),
foreign key (ING_ID) references INGREDIENT(ING_ID)
);      

CREATE TABLE ING_SUPP(
ING_ID          VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,   
SUPP_ID         VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
SUPP_PRICE      NUMBER(6,2),
primary key (ING_ID, SUPP_ID),
foreign key (ING_ID) references INGREDIENT(ING_ID),
foreign key (SUPP_ID) references SUPPLIER(SUPP_ID)
);
```

And my query is this:**Which employee served the most number of customers?**
But when I executed these statements:

```
SELECT      MAX (COUNT (O.CUST_ID)) AS "Served customer"
FROM        STAFF S, ORDERS O
WHERE       (S.STAFF_ID = O.STAFF_ID)
GROUP BY    O.STAFF_ID
HAVING      COUNT (O.CUST_ID) > 0;
```

What I got was there was a column named "Served customer" with the maximum number only.
So, now my question is how to display the employee's ID, first name and last name along with 
"Served customer" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is:  "Which employee served the most number of customers? "  Your query does not even return information about the employee, only about the number of customers.

The following aggregation returns for each staff member, the number of customers who were served:

```
SELECT O.STAFF_ID,  COUNT(O.CUST_ID) AS "Served customer"
FROM STAFF SS JOIN
     ORDERS O
     ON S.STAFF_ID = O.STAFF_ID
GROUP BY O.STAFF_ID;
```

To get the maximum number we just need to order this by the count and take the first row.  In Oracle, this uses a subquery:

```
SELECT so.*
FROM (SELECT O.STAFF_ID,  COUNT(O.CUST_ID) AS "Served customer"
      FROM STAFF SS JOIN
           ORDERS O
           ON S.STAFF_ID = O.STAFF_ID
      GROUP BY O.STAFF_ID
      ORDER BY COUNT(O.CUST_ID) DESC
     ) so
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks because of helping me to solve this problem:)